# Data accumulation usign .backward() function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

First, consider the following code blocks in Jupyter Notebook

```
#Block1
import torch
```

```
#Block2
x = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
```

```
#Block3
y = x**10
y.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

Then consider the follwoing code (combining Block2 and Block3 in one cell) :

```
#Block4
x = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
y = x**10
y.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

Every time when I run #Block3, I get acculunated result for print(x.grad) i.e. 10, 20, 30, etc.

But by running #Block4 the answer is always 10

What is the reason behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Case I: When you see different gradient values

It happens because when you call `.grad`, it accumulates the values iteratively, i.e.

1st Call:

```py
>>> grad = None
```

2nd Call:

```py
>>> grad = 10 + grad
>>> grad = 20
```

3rd Call:

```py
>>> grad = 20 + grad
>>> grad = 30
```

And this continues...

##### Case II: When you see the same gradient values

In this second case, a new tensor `x` is created each time you run your programming block. New memory will be allocated to these tensors, and grads will be initialized to `0`. Therefore, you always get 10 in this case.

I hope it helps. Thanks!